# PHP: Counting values in an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have a databse class which returns an array of objects. I am trying to get multiple bits of data from this single query, in order to prevent having to run three queries.

I have stumbled upon `array_count_values()` [ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php ] which will be perfect for catching various bits of data about the result set which I can use. Although I can't figure out how to cast all the second dimensions into arrays without having to just foreach through the whole return which would be a little bad I think.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can convert my array of objects, as a whole into an array, to allow this game changing function to do it's magic?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [message_id] => 23185
            [from_profile] => 3165
            [to_profile] => 962
            [parent_message_id] => 17111
            [date_sent] => 2011-02-23 05:48:25
            [subject] => RE: hi
        )
// etc
```

There is also the issue that I've just thought of whilst typing this question, sods law eh? That will the function be able to parse multiple dimensions?

Comment: What property from the objects are your counting? Or are you not counting values from the objects?

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you mean something like [array_walk_recusrive](http://php.net/array-walk-recursive)?

Comment: Your expected result is not Clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to alter the first dimension, you can use [array_walk](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
$dbResultsArray = // db results here

array_walk($dbResultsArray, function(&$elem) { $elem = (array)$elem; });
```

`$dbResultsArray` is passed by reference so once `array_walk` has run your `$dbResultsArray` is already updated.

I'm using closures which require php 5.3+ but you can use [create_function](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) in older versions.

Comment: Yep, this seems to be okay, as it will allow me to convert all the elements. Although not perfect as it's still looping.

Answer (score 1):

I am not much clear what you are talking about but there is a function which can count array elements as well as object properties.

[count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Hence you do not need to convert object into array for this purpose.

Comment: I don't want to count the array, but what's in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try something like

`$result = array_count_values(array_map(function ($message) {
    return $message->id;
 }, $messageArray));`

Answer (score 0):

do a for loop on your array of objects, and typecast them as `(array)` and assign them back,
you won't need to go inside further nesting,it will only typecase topmost level.

eg;

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($myObjArr as $t){
  $arr = (array)$t;
  $newArr[] = $arr;
}
```

Comment: A good suggestion, but I'd rather not foreach a loop which could be about 300 odd results.

Answer (score 0):

This might be able to point you in the right direction;

http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass

As far as muliple dimensions go, I'm not sure on that one.  Hopefully the above is helpful though.